# Swift: convert String to NSTextField

Tags: swift

When I try to convert a string to an NSTextField using the following code

```
test?.stringValue = red_str
```

test returns "nil". test is the name of an outlet of type NSTextField! which is connected to an NSTextField in my view. I determined this by single stepping the app past this statement. The quantity "red_str" is a valid string. Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is the function in which the statement is embedded:

```
@IBAction  func redValue(sender: NSSliderCell) {
    red = Float(sender.doubleValue)
    let red_str = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%6.2f", red)
    test?.stringValue = red_str
    self.needsDisplay = true }
```

The view displays a graph which depends upon the parameter "red" which is updated with the slider. The graph displays (and updates) perfectly; the value of red does not display in the TextView.

For reference, here is the outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var test: NSTextField!
```

Comment: A common mistake is trying to access outlets before they have been setup.  
Please show what lifecycle function you are executing this statement in. E.g is it viewDidLoad?

Comment: Thanks. See above -- I have edited the original query.

Comment: `test` returns `nil`, it means you haven't initialize it yet.

Comment: When and how is `redValue` being called?

Comment: redValue is the name of the slider which sets the variable "red". This works fine, since the graph is redisplayed with the correct value. The only problem is that the outlet doesn't work, despite being connected properly.

Comment: The equivalent code in Objective-C works fine -- I guess Swift is very particular about something that I haven't done properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up the relationship between test @IBOutlet and your storyboard or xib file.

Comment: They are properly connected, if that is what you mean. I checked using the Connections Inspector for the TextField.